Form Builder: Create Contact and add to (static) group
I've created a from via Form Builder which allows staff to create contacts more easily. It works fine but I am missing one functionality: Adding the contact to a group.
Is anyone aware if this is supported in Form Builder? And if so, how?

Yes this feature was recently added and will be included with the upcoming (5.77) release.

Great, thanks for the quick response!
